# Access isvalid property of ASP.NET validators in Javascript

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation

I have read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx) that any ASP.NET validator has a property called: `isvalid`. This property can be used in client side to check if the validator successfully passed the validation or not.

I tried to access this property as following but for some reason the code fail:

```
alert(document.getElementById("validator_clientID").isvalid);
```

Do you have any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Please post the validator declaration, along with your full JavaScript. Also, clarify what you mean by 'with no luck'. What error do you receive? Displaying the current status of the isvalid attribute using the method you supplied worked for me. I suspect the id you are using (validator_clientID) is incorrect.

Comment: I have tried accessing it like that and it works:
bool flag = validatorname.isvalid;

For some reason, accessing isvalid through the object direct was accessible. But I don't know why getting the element using getElementById didn't retrieve the object. I have tried it event using the validator ID - not the ClientID - and it's still unaccessible. I got undefined value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found same !

try this `document.getElementById('XXX').Validators[0].isvalid` It's working for me

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the isvalid works on a validator control directly as this is a server side validation function.  You can fire a validator check for the current page or validation group using the client side javascript function `Page_ClientValidate`.  You can optionally specify a validation group name a parameter.  This will return true if all the validation passes.

You can also look at more available client-side functions and how they map to the server side functions on MSDN at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0.aspx

Comment: @mnour just following up, did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: This worked for me.  Looks like... `var isValid = Page_ClientValidate();`

Answer (score 1):

Kindly have a look at the solution below that iterates through all validators and display validators which are invalid at the client side

```
var varray=new Array(); 
for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++)
 {
   if(!Page_Validators[i].isvalid)
    {
      varray.push(Page_Validators[i])
    }
 }
 varray;
```

You can paste this code in console to get invalid validators

Answer (score 0):

Remember to call

```
IsValid
```

instead

```
isvalid
```

(may vary)

Answer (score 0):

On client side Javascript:

```
var controlIsValid = this.document.getElementById("validatorID").attributes.isvalid.value;
```